# libGDX not setting up the "__libgdx_setup_tmp" file

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, installation

Screenshot of what is appearing:

[image]

So after creating a new project, this is what I'm met with. When I import the project to eclipse, it's still a rar file, rather than an actual project that I can expand.

Here's a picture of what I just described:

[image]

How do I go about fixing this? I read that I need to go into the directory and make it so that "write" is enabled, so it can create it, but that option was already checked. So I'm confused on what my next step should be.

Comment: Start the Setup UI as admin meight help

Comment: That actually prompted me to find the UAC and turn it off, so I automatically ran it as an admin. Thanks for the good advice!